# Docker daemon unable to run with AUFS on Debian 7

Tags: docker, filesystems, debian, daemon

I'm running a Debian Wheezy server in GCE. We have Docker containers using the AUFS storage driver. Something changed recently, and today I am unable to connect to the docker daemon.

Example output from running
`docker daemon --storage-driver=aufs`

`FATA[0001] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported`

All the other answers to this question are either a) `rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs`, ie start completely over or b) `--storage-driver=overlay2`, run with a different storage driver. However I do not want to lose my containers, and I haven't found a way to export them without the daemon running with the aufs storage driver.

I've been all over the internet looking up solutions. The official docs (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/aufs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-aufs-storage-driver) say my Debian version is supported (7.12) and my kernel version is supported (3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64).

If I run the daemon with storage-driver=devicemapper docker connects as expected, however of course none of my containers are there as they are in the AUFS system.

When I run `/proc/filesystems | grep aufs` the result is blank, however aufs is present as a module at `/lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/fs/aufs/aufs.ko`.

From the docker site I downloaded and ran the script here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/master/contrib/check-config.sh

The output includes:
`CONFIG_AUFS_FS: enabled (as module)`

Other advice I've come across uses `modprobe`, when I do `sudo modprobe aufs` I get the error

`ERROR: could not insert 'aufs': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)`

and then `dmesg | grep aufs` shows this error line:

`aufs: Unknown symbol setfl (err 0)`

From there I ran `modinfo aufs` and got this block of output, which I frankly don't know what to do with:

> filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64/kernel/fs/aufs/aufs.ko
>
> staging:        Y
>
> alias:          fs-aufs
>
> version:        3.16-20140908+setfl
>
> description:    aufs -- Advanced multi layered unification filesystem
>
> author:         Junjiro R. Okajima
>
> license:        GPL
>
> srcversion:     986E0DDDAA9BDCB0E005DF4
>
> depends:
>
> intree:         Y
>
> vermagic:       3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
>
> parm:           brs:use /fs/aufs/si_*/brN (int)
>
> parm:           allow_userns:allow unprivileged to mount under userns (bool)

I'm at a loss how to proceed, I can't really tell if the error is with docker itself or with the aufs dependency. I also do not know what could have changed in the last day or so to make my system change behavior. I know I'm a few version behind on some of the software, what can I safely upgrade to get docker working with aufs again? Or what else can I try?

Comment: Not a elegant solution, but try this. Create a new machine with docker and aufs. See if the setup works. If it works then copy the aufs folder over to the new machine and see if that works. If it does, discard the old machine

Comment: Thanks Tarun. Thoughts on how I can move aufs across machines?

Comment: You can simply use scp